# Can't show api data in qml table correctly

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

I'm trying to get data from an api and insert it into table view from python side.
Code.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 1200
    height: 500
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("TableView")

    Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "#50505f"

    TableView {
        id: table

        anchors.fill: parent
        model: libraryModel

        rowDelegate: Rectangle {
            color: styleData.selected ? "5a53ff" : "#40405f"
            width: 2000
            height: 40
            border.width: 1
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "title"
            title: "Title"
            width: 500
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "author"
            title: "Author"
            width: 500
        }
    }
}

// Connections {
//     target: backend
// }
}
```

main.py

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import os
import sys
from turtle import title
import requests
import json

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    # Get Context
    # main = MainWindow()
    url = "http://localhost:8085/api/supplier"
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    id = []
    name = []
    for obj in response:
        id.append(obj["supplier_id"])
        id.append(obj["supplier_name"])
    myModel = []

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("libraryModel", id) 

    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I understand what the error is, basically when the it calls the api it sets the first value it gets and sets it to both the fields, I want the data to be separated (id should go to title and name to author), but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Any help would be really appreciated. I've been working on it for quite a while and can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a model with custom roles associated with "title" and "author":

```py
import os
import sys
import requests
import json

from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Qt, Slot, Signal
from PySide2.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

AUTHOR_ROLE = Qt.UserRole
TITLE_ROLE = Qt.UserRole + 1


class LibraryModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setItemRoleNames({AUTHOR_ROLE: b"author", TITLE_ROLE: b"title"})

    def append(self, author, title):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setData(author, AUTHOR_ROLE)
        item.setData(title, TITLE_ROLE)
        self.appendRow(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()

    library_model = LibraryModel()

    # Get Context
    url = "http://localhost:8085/api/supplier"
    response = requests.get(url).json()

    for obj in response:
        author = obj["supplier_name"]
        title = obj["supplier_id"]
        library_model.append(author, title)

    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("libraryModel", library_model)

    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```